# Implement DISPID_VALUE in C# and call it from C++

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a C++ COM module that accept IDispatch interfaces and on certain condition invoke them using `DISPID_VALUE`. This method work very well in C++. Now I have a client in C# and I want to implement an object that implement `IDispatch` and have a method with `DISPID` = 0(`DISPID_VALUE`). I already tried this:

```
// This will generate invalid cast
[ComVisible(true)]
class Callback1
{
    [DispId(0)]
    void Execute(object arg) {...}
}

// This also generate invalid cast
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("163AC24E-90DB-47D4-8580-EBB21E981FBF"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
interface ICallback2
{
    [DispId(0)]
    void Execute(object arg) ;
}
[Guid("842A7754-7CE6-4991-9E12-3FAB2367591A"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICallback2))]
class Callback2 : ICallback2
{
    public void Execute(object arg) {}
}
```

Also I don't remember how, but I also write a code that cast successfully but call nothing at all. Now I want to know how should I write a class that implement `IDispatch` and on call an specific method when `DISPID` = 0.

Cast exception is:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.StubHelpers.InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToNative(Object objSrc, IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags)
   at nmclientLib.INMAsyncOperation.AddCallback(Object pCallback)
   at NMTools.RecorderRegistration.BeginConnection(OperationDoneHandler h) in D:\Programming\Version 0.9\A_Project\NMTools\RecorderRegistration.cs:line 166
   at NMTools.ConnectionManager.NoRequestRegisterConnection(RecorderRegistration r, Boolean bConnect) in D:\Programming\Version 0.9\A_Project\NMTools\ConnectionManager.cs:line 396
   at NMTools.ConnectionManager.<InitializeFromDatabase>b__0(Object s, EventArgs e) in D:\Programming\Version 0.9\A_Project\NMTools\ConnectionManager.cs:line 339
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at TestApp1.Program.Main() in D:\Programming\Version 0.9\A_Project\TestApp1\Program.cs:line 18
```

InnerException:

Comment: Code looks okay.  You'll need to do a better job explaining where and how you see an "invalid cast".  DISPID_INVOKE doesn't otherwise mean anything, dispid value 0 is DISPID_VALUE and invariably used for the default property of a COM object.  Execute() is not a property.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok I was mad from the code and write `DISPID_INVOKE` instead of `DISPID_VALUE`. Also DISPID 0 will be used for default properties and default functions, for example in `IE` all JavaScript functions are objects that have a method with DISPID = 0 that execute them, main reason for my class that accept interfaces that implement a function with DISPID = 0, is to support JavaScript from IE!

Comment: [ComVisible] interfaces and classes must be public to be usable.  Is that another typo?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot, I don't know that, do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Did that comment actually solve the problem?

Comment: @HansPassant Making the type `public` solve it. I'm pretty new to `.NET` and I don't really know things like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it is clear from the comments what the problem was.  You must declare [ComVisible] interfaces and classes **public**.  The CLR honors accessibility, a COM client doesn't get to use internal types when a .NET program cannot do so either.

A better exception message would have been nice, but that's par for the course in COM error handling.  Which doesn't otherwise have anything similar to accessibility constraints so there isn't a more specific error code than E_NOINTERFACE.  Which gets translated to InvalidCastException.

Notable is that this is very rare, using a [ComVisible] .NET class in a .NET application doesn't make much sense.  Just use the class directly by adding a reference to the assembly.  You'll get rid of the registration requirement, the ducky error messages and a chunk of overhead in a method call.  Modulo some kind of COM layer you cannot get rid of, that happens.